# Difference between Turning off a computer and Restarting it?

Tags: reboot, shutdown

What is the difference between restarting the computer and turning it off and powering it on again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power-cycling a system *very slightly* reduces its life.  In operation, chips and other components are warm.  Cooling and then rewarming them enough times will eventually make something crack--a capacitor, a solder joint, something.  Also, a "warm" boot is faster than a cold start because almost all computers skip the RAM check on warm boots.

Comment: Also power cycling a computer allows for changing the settings of various processor MSR options (like enabling VT-x), which soft rebooting does *not* do.

Answer (score 2):

Automation really. Restarting just allows the computer to turn the computer off and on for you. In reality, the power isn't actually toggled off on a restart, but rather the computer literally "restarts", dumping its memory and starting from scratch.

There isn't really any benefit to turning the computer off and back on again, restart is sufficient.

Comment: Some processor and bios options can only take effect with a power cycle.

Comment: I've had issues with hardware where a power cycle would work but not a warm reboot. For instance, every couple of months the WiFi chipset (Broadcom) on my HP Pavilion laptop stops working.  Warm boots do nothing, but a power cycle always corrects the problem.